# How do I perform a find using $geoIntersects / 2dsphere in an array subfield?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection with documents and each has a field array with polygons.

I want to test if my polygon geoIntersects any of those polygons. They are all box-shaped if it helps.

I will add bounty points if you add in the possibility of having my polygon in that array I'm testing. I wouldn't want it intersect with itself...

Cities:

```
{_id, buildings:[ {coo:{shape:"Polygon", coordinates:[ [0,0], [4,0], [4,5], [5,0],[0,0] ] }, {coo:{shape:"Polygon", coordinates:[ [0,0], [4,0], [4,5], [5,0],[0,0] ] } ] }}
```

Imagine I have around 100 or so elements in the array.
I want to determine if, for a given shape, that might be included inside the array, if it intersects any or none of the other polygons (again, excluding itself it is in there).

Comment: Could you include a sample document?  That will clarify your schema.

Comment: There you go, edited.

Answer (score 0):

This page will help you make the geospatial index on your compound spatial documents:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/

And then you can use this page to figure out your query

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/box/#op._S_box

Comment: I have read both these pages and my issue is above the information there.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<collection>.findOne({ 'polygons': { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Longitude, Latitude] } } } }
```